# Is one way of returning a user-input value, using a try-except clause, better than the other?

Tags: python, try-except

For context, I am new to Python, and somewhat new to programming in general. In CS50's **"Little Professor"** problem (*details here, but not needed: https://cs50.harvard.edu/python/2022/psets/4/professor/*) my program passes all correctness checks; but, unfortunately, programs aren't checked for efficiency, style or "cleanliness", making those details harder to learn... Therefore, using the function below as an example, I am trying to grasp *how* to think about choosing an implementation when there are multiple options.

In the code below, I have a function that prompts the user to input an int(). If the user inputs 1, 2 or 3, return that value. Otherwise, if the user does not input 1, 2 or 3, or the input is not even an int(), re-prompt the user.

The first includes the conditional within the try block, and breaks if the condition is met, returning the value once out of the loop.

```
def get_level():
    while True:
        try:
            level = int(input("Level: "))
            if 0 < level <= 3:
                break
        except ValueError:
            pass
    return level
```

In the second, once the input has met the int() condition, if the value is 1, 2 or 3, it breaks out of the loop by returning the value of level, similarly re-prompting if not. (**Note**: I noticed the below also works without the "else:" statement, which is a little confusing to me as well, why isn't it needed?)

```
def get_level():
    while True:
        try:
            level = int(input("Level: "))
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            if 0 < level <= 3:
                return level
```

Is one of these examples better to use than the other, and if so, why? Any help is greatly appreciated, but if there is not a specific answer here, thoughts on the overall concept would be incredibly helpful as well!

Comment: Second is better as condition can't raise any exception so no reason to put it inside `try .. except`. Generally better to not use `break`/`continue` if there's another option, it makes code more implicit.

Comment: A lot of this comes down to personal preference.  I like the first block, because it keeps together the code that handles the normal case.  The second block interrupts that flow for the reader.

Comment: I don't know what @OlvinRoght means by con't rais any exception.  That is not true. the rest is personal preference.   I try to write code that generally enters at the top and leaves through a single return so that the flow of the code is a bit clearer.   I would  use your first example.  Second example relies on else being run if no exception thrown.  I think that hides some logic that is clearer in the first example.

Comment: @LhasaDad, I've meant that generally you put in `try .. except` code which could possible raise some exception. `if 0 < level <= 3` is safe so it's not needed to keep it inside.

Comment: See zen of python - https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/ for some general rules on priorities when writing code. I personally would choose the most readable, which to me is the first one.

Comment: @OlvinRoght Thanks for the clarification and that makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you should put as little code as possible inside a `try`, so that you don't misconstrue an unrelated error as the one you're expecting.  It also makes sense to separate the code that obtains the level from the code that acts on it, so that `level` has known validity for as much code as possible.  Both of these points favor the second approach (the second moreso in a larger example), although in this case you could also write it as

```
def get_level():
    while True:
        try:
            level = int(input("Level: "))
        except ValueError:
            continue
        if 0 < level <= 3:
            return level
```

which avoids the `else` indentation.  (You do need that `else` as given, since otherwise if the first input attempt doesn't parse you'll read `level` before assigning to it.)

Meanwhile, the question of `break` *vs.* `return` is really just one of style or conceptualization: do you see the value being in the desired range as meaning "we should stop asking" (`break`) or "we have the answer" (`return`)?

Comment: I would take this a step further; `input` can't raise a `ValueError`, so it should be called *before* the `try` statement. `x = input(...); try: level = int(x); except ValueError: ...`

Comment: (Or more precisely, you aren't planning on catching any exception that `input` *can* raise, so no need to include it in the `try`.)

Comment: @chepner: Fair enough, although obviously the more certain we are about an exception's impossibility the less it matters where it is, and it can look stilted to separate it too much.  The `if` is a clearer candidate for extraction since it already stands alone.